# Displaying React component next to a sidebar component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-v4

I am trying to show a header, sidebar and a component. The header and the sidebar should always show. The third component will render depending on what item is clicked on the sidebar.

For the sidebar, I am using material-ui@next `<Drawer />` component. For the navigation I am using `react-router-4` as follows:

**App.js**

```
render() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route component={Header} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Sidebar} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/usernew" component={UserNew} />
      </div>
   </Router>
  )
}
```

I am successfully rendering the desired component. For simplicity, refer to the below code:

**Sidebar.js**

```
...
<List component="nav">
  <ListItem
    button
    component={Link}
    to="/dashboard/usernew"
  >
      New User
  </ListItem>
</List>
...
```

The problem is that the desired component, `<UserNew />`, is not rendering next to the sidebar but below it. Attached is an image to understand my problem better:

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction to display the component next to the `<Sidebar />`?

Comment: Does material-ui automatically set up the position of components for you? or do you have to implement that yourself using CSS?

Comment: Can you provide with code in some online tool? Possibility, you didn't apply css properly. You need to use flex over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's gonna help but I would change some things.

```
render() {
  return (
     <Router>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Route path="/dashboard" render={props => (
            <Drawer
              variant="permanent"
              anchor="left"
            >
              <Route path="/dashboard/usernew" component={UserNew} />
            </Drawer>
          ))}
          />
        </div>
     </Router>
   )
 }
```

1. `Header` will get always rendered so you don't actually need to wrap it in `Route`.
2. [Drawer](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#drawer) requires some props to declare it state so it would be nice if you show what you passed to it in `Sidebar`. My guess is that you try to make [permanent drawer](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#permanent-drawer) which requires that you use `children` props like above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting the children dashboard routes inside the `<Sidebar />` component. The code therefore looks like this:

**App.js:**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route component={Header} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Sidebar} />
        </div>
     </Router>
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
<div>
<Drawer>
<List component="nav">
  <ListItem
    button
    component={Link}
    to="/dashboard/usernew"
  >
      New User
  </ListItem>
</List>
</Drawer>
<div>
   <Route path="/dashboard/usernew" component={UserNew} />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In essence yes, I solved this before viewing your answer. But I will mark yours as correct!